# Create NSManagedObjectSubclasses generate class outside of my project

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, project, nsmanagedobject

I have a problem when i use Create NSManagedObjectSubclasses. When i use it in my Swift project all generated classes file is automatically saved outside of my project structure. Then i need to manually move inside my project with "Copy items if needed" checked every time.

[image: Moving generated classes]

How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: have you considered using mogenerator instead ?

Comment: Ctrl click on the group where you want to add files > New File > Core Data > NSManagedObject subclass

Comment: @Johnykutty Yes in this case it will be generated inside my group folder correctly. However i seen many problems to add Core Data in a current project. In My case i'm lucky and i can start from scratch. Thx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just select group that you need. If you choose Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass, any group of project is not selected by default.

[image]